# HTML and Java Beginner Website Creaton

Tags: java, html

So I understand creating really basic webpages like a hello world web page.
I also understand some basic coding, having taken Java, C++ and even played with some Python and Powershell in my actual job as a Windows Server Admin. These were almost all console programs, interacting with text files local to the system.

I am reading a book on HTML & CSS (havent gotten to the CSS part yet) and I just went through the chapter on forms.

My question is:

How do I write an application in Java or whatever language that sits there and waits for a form to submission to come through so Java has access to that data to do whatever with it?

I feel like I am missing something that everyone else seems as obvious, or is explained as too complex and covered later.

Please point me in the right direction for how you take a basic website, into one that can take input and store it somewhere and then display that input

Comment: This is way too broad. Read about Servlets.

Comment: Or perhaps that is all way to outdated for your purposes; perhaps what you need to do is read into Javascript frameworks and 'single page applications' (SPAs) instead. The server side Java component will then probably be very different, such as a RESTful webservice. Or perhaps you will rather be using Node.js and not use any Java at all, who knows. There is a whole world of possibilities out there, and you will need to spend the time reading into what the possibilities are before you make the wrong choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start studying about jsp and servlet very first. I will suggest you [Head First Jsp And Servlets](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsvlt/) . Try to understand the request and response objects. Learn how Http request and Http Response work.

Comment: Servlets! Ok, maybe that is the magic thing that connects the two. Thank you. I will order and read that book. I looked over the page you linked to and that sounds like it is related.

Comment: I just suggested the book to start. you can prefer your any book of your interest I gave the link of book just because you could know the book better that I am reffering to you. This book is freely available very easily over internet.

Comment: To start with the web thing with java you must know about servlets